# Rails Net::SFTP - is there a way to use an FTP connection (instead of sFTP)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ftp, sftp, net-sftp

We have built a pretty complex plugin inside our system that's using the [Net::SFTP](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-sftp) gem to connect to a remote server. Everything works well.

One of our new customers, though, showed up and prepared for us a server where we can log in only with FTP, not sFTP.

Is there any workaround on how to use this gem to connect to the server using the FTP protocol? Our customer might look into adding access to sFTP. However, if this option would fall, we would need to manage it on our end.

Answer (score 4):

SFTP and FTP  are two completely different protocols.

Net::SFTP supports SFTP only.